# Vim: Vimscript to call netrw command

Tags: vim, netrw

This is a followup (but a distinct question) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002401/vim-detect-whether-im-in-netrw/), which I'll reiterate here for completion.

I have a Vim mapping to start searching (ack-grep with ack.vim plugin) for a pattern from the directory that is the current directory (so the result after :pwd). This mapping works when I'm looking at a buffer.

I want to use the same mapping while I'm in netrw. But, I want to change the current directory (:pwd) to the directory netrw is showing me, so the search will be started from the directory I'm looking at. I know I can do this with the netrw c command. How do I give the `c` command from within a function?

I've tried:

```
function! StartAckSearch()
    " If we're in netrw change the current directory to the directory we're
    " viewing
    if &ft ==# 'netrw'
        echo 'in netrw'
        c                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>a :call StartAckSearch()<CR>
```

And:

I've tried:

```
function! StartAckSearch()
    " If we're in netrw change the current directory to the directory we're
    " viewing
    if &ft ==# 'netrw'
        echo 'in netrw'
        execute 'c'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>a :call StartAckSearch()<CR>
```

But they both don't work.

**Question**
How do I call a netrw command using Vimscript? (If my question can be rephrased to be clearer, please go ahead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `norm c` to call it.

Another way is `exe 'norm c'`

Comment: I've tried `norm c`, which worked. Could you give some more information on why/how this works? Is `norm foo` saying "execute normal command "foo"?

Comment: `:normal gg` is the same as typing `gg` in **NORMAL** mode.

Comment: I know that's the case when you're looking at a file. But why do I have to explicitly say `norm c` when I'm in Vimscript AND in netrw? If I do just `c` the error makes me think it wants to c(hange) stuff.

Comment: `:c` is different from `c`. For example, `:x`(COMMAND mode) is save and quit, but `x`(NORMAL mode) is delete character under cursor. In vim script, you can omit the `:`, so `c` is actually `:c`.